# torch Adamoptimizer produce cuda error in optimizer.step()

Tags: python, pytorch

after add my custom loss function using 3 Torch Linear layer,

i get an cuda error

```
class KLDLoss(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, reduction='sum'):
      super(KLDLoss, self).__init__()
      self.reduction = reduction

  def forward(self, mean, logvar):
    # KLD loss
      kld_loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar - mean.pow(2) - logvar.exp(), 1)
    # Size average
      if self.reduction == 'mean':
        kld_loss = torch.mean(kld_loss)
      elif self.reduction == 'sum':
        kld_loss = torch.sum(kld_loss)
      return kld_loss

class Latent_Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Latent_Classifier, self).__init__()
        layers = []
        layers += [nn.Linear(128, 750)]
        layers += [nn.Linear(750, 750)]
        layers += [nn.Linear(750, 1)]

        self.seq = nn.Sequential(*layers)
  def forward(self, latent_z):
    x = self.seq(latent_z)

    return -torch.mean(torch.log(x)) - torch.mean(torch.log(1 - x))
```

KLDLoss has no error but Latent Classifier has an error after some training phase in `optimizer.step()`

```
105                     denom = (max_exp_avg_sq.sqrt() / math.sqrt(bias_correction2)).add_(group['eps'])
   
106                 else:

--> 107                     denom = (exp_avg_sq.sqrt() / math.sqrt(bias_correction2)).add_(group['eps'])

108 

109                 step_size = group['lr'] / bias_correction1

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

is an error exist in my Latent Classifier code??

optimizer is `AdamOptimizer` and args are `0.0002 lr, (0.5, 0.999)betas`

Answer (score 0):

Those kinds of CUDA errors can be caused by two things in my experience:

- trying to access out-of-bound indices in embedding layers
- trying to perform invalid operations such as the log of zero or a negative value

So my guess is: you are trying to use KLDiv on something that is outside the interval ]0,1[ (excluding 0 and 1). Add a sigmoid activation in the output layer and the problem should be solved...

You can run your code on CPU and you will have an error message that is more meaningful.